# js array.IndexOf not working with objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects, indexof

I am trying to create an array with objects holding day and time. I am looping over a source where there may be duplicates so I want to check each time that I don't already have the current day and time stored.

However, I keep ending up with duplicates. So I figure the array.indexOf maybe doesn't work with objects?

```
    movies.forEach(function(movie){
        if (days.indexOf(movie.day) !== -1) { //if the movie's day exists in our array of available days...
            possibleMovies.push(movie);

            //create a day/time object for this movie
            dt = {day: movie.day, time: movie.time};

            //unless we already have this day and time stored away, do so
            if (possibleTimes.indexOf(dt) === -1) {
                possibleTimes.push(dt);
            }

        }
    });
```

What possibleTimes holds after the loop is done:

```
[ { day: '01', time: '18:00' },
  { day: '01', time: '16:00' },
  { day: '01', time: '18:00' },
  { day: '01', time: '16:00' } ]
```

I would expect line three and four not to be there...

---------- UPDATE ----------

I changed

```
dt = {day: movie.day, time: movie.time};
```

into this

```
dt = JSON.stringify({day: movie.day, time: movie.time});
```

and it works as expected. just need to JSON.parse once I retrieve the data.

Comment: Objects are compared by references, not their contents.

Comment: Oh, thanks. I just tried stringifying it and then it worked as expected, and you just explained why =)

Comment: You should take a look at www.lodash.com

Comment: @MattWelander Careful with stringifying often. That's a relatively expensive operation, where you might just want to iterate and test filtering properties instead. Consider running some performance tests, if performance is critical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

> `indexOf()` compares searchElement to elements of the Array using **strict equality** (the same method used by the **===**, or triple-equals, operator).

That's why that `possibleTimes.indexOf` always results in -1.

Answer (score 3):

Two objects are considered equal if they point to the same location.

```
var obj1 = { x: 100 };
var obj2 = obj1;
console.log( obj1===obj2 );     //  outputs true

var obj1 = { x: 100 };
var obj2 = { x: 100 };
console.log( obj1===obj2 );     //  outputs false
```

You could use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert each object to string and then compare them. Keep in mind that the orders of properties must match.

```
console.log( JSON.stringify( obj1 ) === JSON.stringify( obj2) );    //outputs true
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#uniq), it becomes super easy:

```
let a = [
  { day: '01', time: '18:00' },
  { day: '01', time: '16:00' },
  { day: '01', time: '18:00' },
  { day: '01', time: '16:00' }
];

let b = R.uniq(a);
console.log(b);
```

http://jsbin.com/ligihexate/edit?js,console

Comment: "it becomes super easy" --- your code does not produce the correct result though.

Comment: @zerkms I assume you didn't actually read the code I posted and just ran the JS Bin. It must have been modified when I started playing with the ES6 Set object. The two lines that are commented...uncomment them.

Comment: I've updated the JS Bin example. Sorry for the confusion. I haven't been using it for too long.